# Can i create an object trough parent in js

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance, javascript-objects

I am new to OOJS and I'm a little confused trying to understand inheritance, I created two simple classes, person and student that inherit from person, is there an option to create student by passing data in the parent's constructor? if it's possible, how to do it ? can a child get all the properties and methods  from the parent or only the methods?

**the fname and lName in the alert are undefined

```
function Person(fNme, lName) {
                this.fname = fNme;
               this.lName = lName;
               } 
               Object.prototype.go = function() {
                 alert("I am going now last time you see  "+ this.lName);

            }
            function Student() {
                this.study = function () {
                   alert("I am studing !");
                }
            }

            Student.prototype = new Person();
            var s1 = new Student("sam", "bubu");
            alert(s1.fname +"+"+ s1.lName)
```

Comment: so you want to call `Person()` in `Student()` and pass it arguments right

Comment: yes like in c#, call the parent to use his constructor,if it's possible...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use constructor stealing.

```
  function Student(fName,lName) {
      Person.call(this,fName,lName); 
                this.study = function () {
                   alert("I am studing !");
                }
            }
```

when you call `Student` constructor you can pass along arguments to `Person()` with `call()` to initialize variables in `Person`

Comment: ok, and if i want to add another property to student: name will be taken from the person and average will be added in the student constructor is it possible?... and btw why after declaring of the inheritance this is undefined?
 Student.prototype = new Person();
            var s1 = new Student("sam", "bubu");

Comment: any arguments you want to use in `Person()`,just pass those along in the `Person.call()`.Here's your example : https://jsfiddle.net/o4dyu9m1/

Answer (score 0):

This is done by just calling the parent constructor

```
function Student(fName, lName, whateverelse) {

     Person.call( this, fName, lName ); // call base class constructor function

     this.study = function () {
        alert("I am studing !");
     }
}
```